# passing variables through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to write a script to login to several remote servers and execute a script in each server.
However, I'd like to pass a variable through ssh. Something like this:

```
var="/home/dir/"

  ssh -T $mchname <<'ENDSSH'    
    $var"run_script" < input > output &    
ENDSSH
```

This naive try does not work ($var is simply null). What would be the correct syntax? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the quotes from around `ENDSSH`. They prevent expansion of variables within the [here document](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html#lbBO).

Comment: Ok, this works. But now the control just returns to the main script once "run_script" is finished in $mchname (even though I am using '&'), which is not what I want. How can I fix it? Sorry for the basic  questions. If you want to, you can point me to some ssh tutorial where I can look this things up. Thanks.

Comment: @user1477337: The ampersand is in effect on the destination machine and just means that control returns to the main script more quickly since it doesn't have to wait for `run_script` to complete. But since there's nothing after the `ssh` command and its here document the main script should exit as soon as the `ssh` connection is closed which should be almost immediately. However, if there's some reason that you need to, you can try prefixing `exec` to the `ssh` command: `exec ssh ...` All of this is shell related and mostly isn't specific to `ssh`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var="/home/dir/"

  ssh -T $mchname VAR=$var 'bash -s'<<'ENDSSH'    
    $VAR"run_script" < input > output &    
ENDSSH
```